# How do we get a div attribute from a jquery.post response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr, .post

I have set up two documents on my server, "index.php" and "proc.php". In the "index.php", I wrote some JavaScript code that will send a post request to "proc.php". The proc.php sends a successful response, in the form of a div:

```
<div id="serverResponseDiv" data-class="new-class">
    The request was successful, and this is the response.
</div>
```

When I attempt to get/console.log the "data-class" attribute from the server response, I get an error "undefined".

```
    // index.php script
    ...
    var pst=$.post(site,obj, function(){
        //alert('good');
    } );
    pst.done(function(data) {
        $("#indexDiv").empty().html(data);
        var nClass=$("#serverResponseDiv").attr('data-class');
        console.log(nClass); // for debugging purposes.
        $("#indexDiv").removeClass("old-class").addClass(nClass);
    });
    ...
```

How do I get the attribute value from a server response div? I have done multiple google searches, but cant find the answer to my question. Please help.

Comment: Did you try inspecting the `data` you receive?

Comment: there is definitely no second element with that id on your page (serverResponseDiv), cause that would explain things...

Comment: @JacqueGoupil What would I need to do to inspect the data string, and get the attribute value from there?

Comment: I meant to use a debugger (chrome's dev tools work nicely) and put a breakpoint there, or just console.log() the "data" variable to see what is exactly in it.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the "data" functionality as a attribute.

Try  another ways like class or custom attributes.

I you can not do it, try this:

```
var nClass = $('#serverResponseDiv[data-class="newClass"]');
```

Comment: There is a wrapper div: `<div id="indexDiv"...` that will hold the response data. I want to style it (the wrapper div) with the class that the data-class attribute holds. The data-class attribute could be either "alert-good", "alert-bad", or "alert-neither". I have no way of knowing the data-class attribute before the server sends a response.